# Get time remaining substracting two times - Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to calculate the time remaining to push a notification based on the difference of two times, the first var below has an output of: `2020-07-14 13:31:00 +0000` and I thought to subtract Date() - that. Below is what I'm trying:

```
let prevMealEatenInDateFormat = self.myFormatters.convertStringToDate(inputDate: previousMeal.eaten!)
let newTime = Date() - prevMealEatenInDateFormat
```

but I'm getting this error: `Cannot convert value of type 'Date' to expected argument type 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double')`

What's going on? I need to get the remaining times in hours left

This is the function for `convertStringToDate`:

```
func convertStringToDate(inputDate: String) -> Date {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMM y, hh:mm a"
        dateFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
        dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
        let newDate = dateFormatter.date(from: inputDate)
        
        return newDate!
}
```

Comment: Is `prevMealEatenInDateFormat` a `Date`? Or is it actually a `TimeInterval`?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica check my edited answer. I put the funcion I'm using to convert it to Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this implementation:

```
let currentDate = Date()
let hourRemaining = currentDate.timeIntervalSince(prevMealEatenInDateFormat)
```